# JSON query returns data until I search for it

Tags: sql, json, sql-server, t-sql, json-value

I have a table (code_table) with a lot of different types of records and values.  One of the type of records contains a json field (but not all).  The following returns the records with json fields:

```
select code_data from code_table where code_group='pptoken' 
and code_data like '{%' 
and ISJSON(code_data)=1
```

The query returns:

```
{"orderID":"8L076682TT5438735","subscriptionID":"I-AMJM4M6AX3RP","facilitatorAccessToken":"A21AALhD1svm_MsezAsaFxlEPOGNquXq8YOB3LC8PZ1RTPKr"}
```

However, if I add the value I'm actually searching for, it doesn't work:

```
select code_data from code_table where code_group='pptoken' 
and code_data like '{%' 
and ISJSON(code_data)=1
and JSON_VALUE(code_data,'$.subscriptionID') = 'I-AMJM4M6AX3RP'
```

Returns:

```
Msg 13609, Level 16, State 1, Line 21
JSON text is not properly formatted. Unexpected character '1' is found at position 0.
```

So... I don't understand what's going on.  Why am I getting that error?

Comment: SQL Server does not necessarily apply predicates in the order you specify, it will likely be evaluating the `json_value` function *before* filtering with `isjson`. Try using a row-goal in a sub-query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The optimizer can often rearrange `WHERE` predicates, so `JSON_VALUE` is done before `ISJSON`.

**Do not do what the other answer says, to put it into a CTE.** This often doesn't work either, as the optimizer will combine it all back into one query anyway.

Instead use `CASE` (and derivatives such as `NULLIF` and `IIF`), which is the only construct *guaranteed* to not short-circuit (at least when only scalar values are involved as opposed to aggregate functions).

```sql
select
  code_data
from code_table
where code_group = 'pptoken' 
  and code_data like '{%' 
  and ISJSON(code_data) = 1
  and JSON_VALUE(
    CASE WHEN ISJSON(code_data) = 1 THEN code_data END,
    '$.subscriptionID'
  ) = 'I-AMJM4M6AX3RP';
```

A slightly different syntax, may be more efficient

```sql
  and CASE WHEN ISJSON(code_data) = 1 THEN
       JSON_VALUE(code_data, '$.subscriptionID')
      END = 'I-AMJM4M6AX3RP'
```

Comment: Is there a need for 2x `ISJSON(code_data) = 1`, or did that slip in by accident?

Comment: Yes, I think it's probably best to have a separate filter as well. Given that it's a deterministic function, I would imagine there wouldn't be a perf impact

Answer (score 1):

`JSON_VALUE()` is exploding trying to run on the non-json rows.

Use a `CASE` to prevent `JSON_VALUE()`being executed over non-json values:

```
select code_data
from code_table
where code_group = 'pptoken' 
and code_data like '{%'
and case ISJSON(code_data) when 1 then JSON_VALUE(code_data,'$.subscriptionID') end = 'I-AMJM4M6AX3RP'
```

The case will return `null` for non-json values (which won't be equal to the search value).

Comment: That isn't guaranteed to work either I think. Best is to use a case when

Comment: @sig In what situation would this not work?

Comment: The query optimizer can still perform expansion on the sub-query table expression just like it can with a CTE; using a row-goal however should work, that will force the optimizer to process the rows in the subquery first; possibly a NOEXPAND hint might work, I have never tried.

Comment: I suspect the statement can be unwrapped or at least the possibility would make me consider a case when

Comment: The optimizer isn't stupid, and will just combine this back into one query, so you haven't gained at all. The only way is to use `CASE`

Comment: @stu fair enough. `case` applied looks simple enough (and easy to read).

Comment: @sig good point. hopefully looks better now.

Comment: It's even possible to use `and IIF(ISJSON(code_data)=1, JSON_VALUE(code_data,'$.subscriptionID'), NULL) = 'I-AMJM4M6AX3RP'`. IIF is equivalent to a CASE WHEN with 1 condition, and a bit less verbose.

Comment: Doesnt iif evaluates both arguments before going? Or am I confusing it with how vb6 did it

Comment: @siggemannen No, it translates to the same execution plan as a CASE WHEN with 1 condition and THEN + ELSE parts. `IIF(4>4, 3/0, 2)` returns `2` and not a Divide by zero error.